# un grupo de alumnos no puede usar esa aula si ya esta reservada a esa hora

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Tengo un problema no se como diseñar la solución.
Un grupo de alumnos no puede usar esa aula si ya esta reservada a esa hora.
Por ejemplo no puedes asignar un grupo a una aula que ya esta ocupada con un horario especifico.

**Ejemplo:**
El grupo1 ocupa el laboratorio1 de 12:30 a 3:00 entonces el grupo2 no puede usar ese laboratorio en ese transcurso de tiempo. pero si puede usarlo de 3:00 a 6:00

```
 create table grupo 
(
 id_grupo int not null primary key ,
 nombre_grupo nvarchar (50),
 responsable_grupo int references tprofesor
)
create table Aula
(
 Id_Aula int ,
 Nombre_Aula nvarchar (50),
 Ubicacion_Aula nvarchar (50),
 Descripcion_Aula varchar(50),
 Id_Asignatura int references Asignatura
)
```

Alguna idea como resolver

Comment: Hola Gelder. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Para darte una pequeña idea, te recomiendo que antes de hacer la reserva del laboratorio, compruebes que en ese rango de horas/fecha no tiene ninguna reserva. Aunque no se como pretendes comprobar eso, ya que la tabla `Aula` no tiene ningún campo de fecha/hora.

Comment: ¿Esto es [tag:c#]? A mi no me compila \\(Ô_ô)/

Comment: Como comentan los compañeros, hace falta mas contexto para saber que deseas realizar, pero si es la única información que nos puedes brindar, te recomendaría una tercer tabla que almacene el horario, otro campo para la fecha (ya que tal vez no todos los días este ocupado el salón por ese grupo) y el ciclo escolar (ya que cada ciclo escolar puede cambiar la asignación de las aulas). Espero que estos pobres consejos te ayuden.

Comment: @gbianchi, podria ser un duplicado, pero creo que la respuesta a esta pregunta es que "tiene que verificar si los intervalos se estan compartiendo"

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas agregar otra tabla que relacione los grupos con las aulas. 
como "Reservas"

Reservas tendra 3 campos

1.- ID_Grupo  -- llave foranea a la tabla de grupo
2.- Id_aula   -- llave foranea a la tabla de Aula
3.- Hora_inicial  -- campo tipo fecha o hora
4 - hora_final    -- camo tipo fecha o hora

lo que necesitaras ahora es realizar una restriccion a travez de un trigger o un store procedure.

lo que tienes que revisar es que al hacer una nueva reserva, el salon este desocupado, como puedes hacer esto ?

```
 select * from reserva where Aula = AulaAReservar 
 and (
           (hora_inicial < HoraInicialAreservar and Hora_final > HoraInicialAreservar ) 
        or 
           (hora_inicial > HoraInicialAreservar and hora_inicial < HoraFinalAReservar)
     )
```

La primera condicion dentro del  `AND` es para asegurarnos que no estamos reservando durante el transcurso de una reserva,
el `OR` es para asegurarnos que tampoco hay una reserva enmedio del periodo que queremos reservar.

si el resultado de arriba regresa algun resultado, significa que no puedes reservar en esa aula durante ese periodo